# Import autocad drawing in Python

Tags: python, autocad, comtypes

I've a big problem using the [`import` method](http://help.autodesk.com/view/ACD/2015/ENU/?guid=GUID-5B441D77-BE99-454A-AAE3-9E19731B07D5) of Atocad ActiveX, the doc says its signature is:

```
RetVal = (Document)object.Import((String)FileName, (Variant (three-element array of doubles))InsertionPoint, (Double)ScaleFactor)
```

I'm using the following snippet of code:

```
import array
import comtypes.client
acad = comtypes.client.GetActiveObject("AutoCAD.Application")
doc = acad.ActiveDocument
ms = doc.ModelSpace
doc.Import("C:/path/to/the/drawing.dwg", array.array('d', [0, 0, 0]), 1.0)
```

But I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File ".\script.py", line 30, in <module>
    doc.Import("C:/path/to/the/drawing.dwg", array.array('d', [0, 0, 0]), 1.0
)
_ctypes.COMError: (-2147024809, 'The parameter is incorrect.', (u'Invalid argument', u'AutoCAD', u'C:\\Program Files\\Au
todesk\\AutoCAD 2015\\HELP\\OLE_ERR.CHM', -2145320901, None))
```

The problem is: which parameter is incorrect?!! Usually I always pass coordinates to autocad methods as I did in the second argument, it always works, can you please help me?

**EDIT** I've tried to pass `[0.0, 0.0, 0.0]` same error

Comment: I would normally except to pass a normal list instead of an array. Have you tried simply `[0, 0, 0]` rather than the array? Also, `0` is an int. Try `0.0`.

Comment: Have you tried: Dim point(0 To 2) As Double   :     point(0) = 1.0 : point(1) = 1.0 : point(2) = 1.0     :      acadDoc.Import("yourpath", point, 1.0) ?

Comment: @DavidK.Hess arrays must be passed as safeArrays, this is why array.array must be used, also, d converts int to double

Comment: @EdwardBagby I'm coding in Python not VBA!

Comment: Have you tried using `open` on that file path to prove that the file is really available where you think it is right at that moment?

Comment: @DavidK.Hess yes, it exists, unfortunately with open it doesn't import as a block but a mere drawing... anyway, I found a workaround, thanks for your precious help

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if you ever figured it out, but you get the COMError whenever there is a pending command in AutoCAD. The COMError is because both your script and the program itself are trying to access the same interface. You need to manually hit escape twice in AutoCAD and it shouldn't give you the error. If you ever find a way to make the python code use the COM interface to hit escape for you, let me know.

Comment: it's been a very long time but I remember that what you said is true, usually I wait (sleep function) a few seconds before begining manipulating the draw after acad starts